# Logo with circle in JPEG renders as oval in development but OK in public-facing site

Tags: html, css, jpeg, adobe-illustrator

I'm viewing a page of my public site at http://tcb.cbmiweb.com/UIForms/Subscribing.aspx and the graphic someone else built with Adobe Illustrator renders "properly" as a circle.

I am using Google Chrome and the Developer Tool. I snap the public page to one-side of my monitor and snap the development (intranet) equivalent page to the other side. Using Google Tools I compare the pixel dimensions of the aspnetForm and the DIVs masterContainer and masterLogo and notice they are identical. Here are some key screenshots from the intranet/dev site for comparison: [image: greenshot taken with 2 Chrome windows snapped dividing screen]

I have used WinDiff to compare the content of the public site to the intranet site and everything of relevance is identical. Obviously, the JPEG graphic itself is different in the public site (e.g. "Beta" versus "Development". The byte size of the public file is 26kb while the "oval" problem for the intranet site is 37kb. When I look at both files with MS Paint they look very similar (i.e. both "round", no "oval-ing", etc.). All the HTML and CSS for each are the same.

Both are served up by IIS 6.0 running on different instances of Windows Server 2003. The only thing I can think of is some obscure setting inside the Graphics program, which is Adobe Illustrator which I don't use. Is this "distortion" anything the web developer can control?

UPDATE: Both images are the same width; a function sets the .ImageURL property in the Site.Master.aspx.vb code-behind file. Here is some more info (identical in both public and private site):

```
#masterLogo
{
    width: 20%; display: table-cell; text-align: left; 
}

<div id="masterContainer">
<div id="masterLogo">
    <asp:Image ID="imgTCBLogo" runat="server" ImageAlign= "Top" 
            CausesValidation="False" 
            Width="180px" Height="100px">
    </asp:Image>
</div>

Me.imgTCBLogo.ImageUrl = UIF.SetLogoForMasterPage()
```

Finally, here is the rendered IMG tag from "view page source" (from the "oval-ish" site):

```
        <img id="ctl00_imgTCBLogo" CausesValidation="False" src="../Images/TCBlogo-development-small.JPG" align="top" style="height:100px;width:180px;border-width:0px;" />
```

Comment: If you re-download the oval version of the image file, aka save it from the intranet site via your web browser to your computer, and then open it ... is it round?

Comment: Yes, it is round but let me be clear what I did. From Chrome browser, I right-clicked on the "oval" image and saved it to by local harddrive then opened it and it looks properly round. Default viewer of this .JPG saved to my PC is Picassa Photo Viewer but there are many "Open With" choices. I did NOT moved this SAVED file to my Development server. Is this helpful? Did I go "far enough" with your idea?

Answer (score 0):

Are both images the same width? If both images are different widths then setting an explicit width in the css could cause one to stretch and get distorted. Your screenshot doesn't actually show the image tag itself so it's hard to see.

Comment: Thanks Eric. See update to original post hopefully answering your question.